# Can Wix silently not overwrite a database

Tags: database, installation, wix

Wix can obviously prompt/tell the user that a database exists, and give them the choice to overwrite or to cancel the install. Unfortunately the user cannot specify to 'not overwrite' and carry on with the install.

Therefore, can Wix silently not overwrite a database? If the database is present, just ignore and carry onto the next instruction.

If not, is there another way to achieve the fact a reinstall needs to occur and the database is already in place?

Current my Wix fragment looks like this:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="COMPG_MyProductDatabase" Directory="TARGETDIR">
      <Component Id="COMPG_MyProductDatabase.sql" Guid="{...}">
        <File Id="FILE_MyProductDatabase.sql" Source="..\MyProduct.Cache.Database\MyProduct.Deployment.sql" Name="MyProduct.Deployment.sql" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>

      <Component Id='COMP_MyProductDatabase' Guid='{...}'>
        <CreateFolder/>
        <sql:SqlDatabase Id='DB_MyProductDatabase' Database='MyProduct' Server='[PROP_DATABASESERVERNAME]'
          CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='yes' ConfirmOverwrite='yes'>
          <sql:SqlScript Id='SQL_MyProductDatabase' BinaryKey='FILE_MyProductDatabase' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
        </sql:SqlDatabase>
      </Component>
   </ComponentGroup>
    <Binary Id='FILE_MyProductDatabase'  SourceFile='..\MyProduct.Cache.Database\MyProduct.Deployment.sql' />
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the database creation into your SQL script then use SQL statements to do the conditional logic. Change the SqlDatabase elemnt to connect to 'master' for this to work.